# Why OVER (ORDER BY row_id) not work in python?

Tags: sqlite, python-3.7

I'm using python 3.7 and SQLite3. Test following code in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=53c6c36ce8defbfb5af3cebb0d16d598) It works fine but when I using it in python It say "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error"

This code I using in db<>fiddle:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT row_id, invoice_no, product_id, quantity, price, sum(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY row_id) AS total FROM  product_in)
SELECT *FROM cte WHERE  total > 200
ORDER  BY row_id;
```

This code I using in python:

```
product = cur.execute("""
WITH cte AS (SELECT row_id, invoice_no, product_id, quantity, price, sum(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY row_id) AS total FROM product_in)
SELECT *FROM cte WHERE  total > 99
ORDER  BY row_id
            """)
```

What is my mistake?
How can I get solution?

Comment: Check your version of SQLite. Window functions are supported since version 3.25.0

Comment: @forpas SQLite version 3.35.2

Comment: If your version is 3.35.2 then the code should run fine. Execute `select sqlite_version();`.

Comment: @forpas I updated the SQLite version and it works fine. Thank you so much.